# finding an equation through these two points in upper half plane

Tags: geometry

I have to find an equation going through $(-1,y)$ and $(1,y)$. The equation my book uses is $x^2+y^2+ax=b$. So I get two equations when I plug in the two points. I get $1+y^2-a=b$ and $1+y^2+a=b$ where $a=0$ and $b=1+y^2$. Pluging them back I get $x^2+y^2=1+y^2$ is just $x^2=1$ which is just a parabola and not a semicircle. Is thus supposed to happen again in the upper half plane model?

Comment: $x^2=1$ is a pair of parallel lines not a parabola.

Comment: I suppose the two $y$ are indeed different things. The first $y$ is a given value, and the second $y$ is a undeterminate. If this is the case, just renaming the second to avoid name clash.

Comment: Oh OK. I'll do that then. Maybe it is a typo.

Comment: Nope that does not work either. I keep getting x^2=1.

Comment: The line $Y=y$ goes through your two points, where I am using $Y$ for the variable to avoid conflict with your given $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's ignore your text book for a moment. You have the two points $(-1,y)$ and $(1,y)$ and are looking for a circle through these which is perpendicular to the $x$ axis. So the circle center must lie on that axis, and since both points lie symmetrically around the $y$ axis, the center of the circle has to be the origin. So you have the equation $X^2+Y^2=r^2$ for the circle. I use capital letters for the variable point in your equation, as opposed to the lower case $y$ in your problem statement points. Now you plug in one of your points and obtain $r=1^2+y^2=y^2+1$. So the equation of your circle is $$X^2+Y^2=y^2+1$$ with $X$ and $Y$ denoting a point to be checked and $y$ the coordinate from your defining points.

Comparing this to your textbook format, you will see that the $b$ corresponds to $r^2$ in this case. The $a$ term accounts for the fact that the center *might* have been in some other location along the $x$ axis. So your $a=0,b=1+y^2$ was correct, but the part about plugging things back was incorrect and probably due to the duplicate use of the variable $y$.